# Closed form for the definite integral $\int_3^5\exp\left[\frac{-3.91}{V}\left(\frac{\lambda}{0.55}\right)^{-q}R\right]\,\mathrm d\lambda$

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form

I am stuck on the following definite integral:
$$\tau=\int_3^5\exp\left[\frac{-3.91}{V}\left(\frac{\lambda}{0.55}\right)^{-q}R\right]\,\mathrm d\lambda$$
Is it possible to solve it in a closed form ?
Thanks.

Comment: For future questions, please try to make the title of your question more informative (I've done so for you now). E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* In particular, remember that titles may comprise 150 characters and support TeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the limits of the integration are pretty "exotic" (not $0,1$ or $\infty$), I would only expect the closed form if the indefinite integral has it. For the latter, [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-3.91%2aR%2FV%2a%28%5B%5Clambda%5D%2F0.55%29%5Eq%5D%2C%5B%5Clambda%5D%5D) gives relatively closed solution which may be of interest to you - just follow the link.